# Can vintage strobes damage wireless receivers?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

It is well documented that some old strobes can damage digital cameras. However, I couldn't find information about any potential damage from using a wireless transmitter on camera and receivers or transceivers on old flashes.

I am talking about vintage consumer grade flashes, "modern" shoe mount designs using AA batteries, like from the 1980s, not single-use flashbulbs or X-mount flashcubes.

Comment: to clarify, i guess, concern is with shorting voltage. "Firing" of the flash be camera causes short circuit in hot-shoe contacts, and voltage can be as high as 400V going through camera https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_shoe#Voltages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is the possibility that vintage strobes with high trigger voltages can damage wireless receivers/transceivers attached to them. The danger would only apply to the receiver/transceiver physically connected to the flash via either hot shoe connection or PC cord. There is no danger to the transmitter and camera connected to the receiver via wireless radio.

Each trigger design varies on a case-by-case basis. If you are concerned about using a particular flash you should probably contact the trigger manufacturer's customer support department for information about how much voltage the trigger is designed to tolerate. Then compare it to the trigger voltage of the flash in question. The user instructions with some triggers warn to not exceed a specified voltage. Others don't specify the designed voltage tolerance.